# Creating an LTspice model of a MOSFET not in the standard library

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I want to model [this power MOSFET](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/240/VMO1200-01F-1548154.pdf) in LTspice.

[image]

I went into the standard library and noticed that all the MOSFETs there are created by VDMOS(...). Reading up on this command in [this resource](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm), I noticed that there are many parameters required by VDMOS that are not in the datasheet of my desired component.

For example, I read [elsewhere](http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_6.htm) that Cgdmax and Cgdmin can be read off a Crss chart, but that's not in the datasheet either. Likewise the tranconductance Kp or the gate/drain/source resistances.

Is there any chance I can model the component realistically? Can some parameters be neglected or set to reasonable default values?

Comment: It's not as simple as mapping datasheet values to model parameters.  I suggest using the VDmostool found on the [LTspice Google Groups](https://groups.io/g/LTspice) (free membership required to access files):   https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/Model%20Tools/Board%20Level%20MOSFET%20%28VDmos%29/Software